# PyCuda mem_alloc initialization error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pycharm, pycuda

```
in desaturate_image
    redarray_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(self.redarray.nbytes)
pycuda._driver.LogicError: cuMemAlloc failed: initialization error
```

I get the above error on this line:

```
redarray_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(self.redarray.nbytes)
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import pycuda.autoinit
```

This import statement fixed the issue. My best guess is that the device was not initialized